# How to halve a very large even integer without getting an float overflow error?

Tags: python

I have an expression where I halve very large even integers, and I know the numerators are even so there is no fractional part, but I get an overflow error *"OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float"* because internally Python converts to floats.

`return int(n/2) if (n%2) == 0 else int((3*n+1)/2)`

I can fix this with mpmath via `int(mpf(n)/2) if (n%2) == 0 else int(mpf(3*n+1)/2)` but it runs 3x slower than native division and I am looping millions of times so this is too long.

Is there an efficient way to halve a very large even integer?

---

Some have suggested integer division `//` and I have tested it. The stats are: -

- Using `/` 45 tests per sec
- Using `//` 5 tests per sec
- Using `mpf` 12 tests per sec
- Using `>>` 5 tests per sec

The integers I am working with are of the order `2**2000` but I want to consider larger ones so I need a method that works on unbounded integers.

Comment: How large is this large number? Also, what happens if you try `n >> 1`?

Comment: Integer division `//`?

Comment: Looping millions of times and "too long" seems to be typical for Python. Maybe a different programming language would be faster.

Comment: Python is strongly typed and does not internally convert integers to floats. You explicitly converted to floats with the `/` operator.

Comment: @Woodford Not sure what about that you think is explicit. If you know that's what the `/` operator does then you will know that's what's going to happen, but there is nothing in the code which *explicitly* says there is a conversion happening.

Comment: if you have a _great many_ values to convert or need to repeat the calculation with some frequency, you may instead want to work with a scientific python library like [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html), which will be _much_ faster than native Python

Comment: @Woodford practically, Python is [Duck Typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), so objects which behave like a float can still be made of wood!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `//` for integer division or `>>` to bit-shift it

```py
>>> 10 / 2   # results in float
5.0
>>> 10 // 2  # results in int
5
>>> 10 >> 1  # bit shift
5
>>> f"{10:04b}"  # binary format display
'1010'
>>> f"{5:04b}"   # shows shift
'0101'
```

Demo on a big number

```
>>> _ = 10**10000 / 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
>>> _ = 10**10000 // 2
>>> (10**10000 >> 1) == (10**10000 // 2)
True
```

Beware, you must coerce non-int inputs in either case

```py
>>> 10.0 / 2
5.0
>>> 10.0 // 2
5.0
>>> 10.0 >> 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'float' and 'int'
```

Take a look at the [PEP 238 Abstract](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/#abstract) which introduced the split of `/` vs `//` and the rest for a little about how this is implemented as `__div__()` (now [`__truediv__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truediv) as of some more recent revision) and [`__floordiv__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv) methods on instances of `int`

Answer (score 0):

Both of these options seem pretty fast:

```
In [387]: n = int("12" * 10_000)

In [388]: %timeit n//2
20.6 µs ± 593 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [389]: %timeit n>>1
3.81 µs ± 37.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

You can use `wombo_combo = lambda x : x>>1 if x%2 == 0 else (3*x + 1)>>1`

Edit:

I think if you're looking to speed things up you can also do something like this, which is slightly faster than `%`

```
if n & 1 == 0: # even
    return n >> 1
# odd
return (n*3 + 1) >> 1
```

Here are more timings for you:

```
In [78]: n = 2**2000

In [79]: %timeit n>>1 if n&1==0 else (n*3+1)>>1
288 ns ± 8.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [80]: %timeit n//2 if n&1==0 else (n*3+1)//2
566 ns ± 5.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [81]: %timeit n//2 if n%2==0 else (n*3+1)//2
965 ns ± 3.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Also if you know the numerator is always positive you should just avoid doing the conditional check. That's extra wasted time that could be spent shifting them bits!